# Eclipse Intellisense Information

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

When I am using intellisense for Eclipse and the intellisense dropdown appears with the list of classes I can select from; is there a way to read about what each class does from the dropdown list?

Comment: What is "Eclipse Intellisense"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc comments for the class, from the jar file that contains the class,  should be automatically displayed.  Of course, this depends on there actually **being** javadoc comments...